# Using Python to find minima and maxima?

Tags: scipy

I try to differentiate my function in python but receive a "can't convert expression to float" error. I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
import math
from math import pi
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import sympy
from sympy import symbols, diff
import numpy



def function(x, y, t):
    e = 1.65e-21
    s = 3.4e-10
    return 4*e*((s/x)**12 - (s/x)**6) + 4*e*((s/y)**12 -(s/y)**6) + 4*e*((s/math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 - 2*x*y*math.cos(math.degrees(t))**12 - (s/math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 - 2*x*y*math.degrees(math.cos(t))))**6)))

    x, y, t = sympy.symbols('x k t')

    sympy.diff(function(x, y, t), t)
```

I went to the website and tried to implement some suggestion but I am still having problems.

Prompt assistance highly appreciated

Comment: fix your indentation

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `math` functions with sympy - use sympy functions. For example a cosine:

```
sympy.cos
```

A sqrt is simply:

```
x**0.5
```

sympy has all math functions built in though, including sqrt.